# HTML and PHP drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

It's actually an API integration with the server.
Here's PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['generate'])) 
{
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/GetResponseAPI.class.php';
    $api = new GetResponse($aid);
    $campaigns   = (array)$api->getCampaigns();
    $campaignIDs = array_keys($campaigns);
    $campaign    = $api->getCampaignByID($campaignIDs[0]);
    var_dump($campaigns, $campaign);
}
```

Here's the HTML code for the dropdown menu:

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate" name="Generate" id="Generate"/>
        </br>
        <select name="Campaign" id="Campaign">
        <option value="Option1"><?php echo $campaign;?></option>
        <option value="Option2"><?php echo $campaignIDs;?></option>
        <option value="Option3"><?php echo $campaigns;?></option>
        </select>
```

I'm actually looking for those 2 to communicate .
Example , when user enter their API and hits generate.
I want the dropdown to list down the possible campaign .

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Whats the values you getting in $campaigns ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate" name="Generate" id="Generate"/>
    </br>
    <select name="Campaign" id="Campaign">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through Campaign, Provided you need to build a campaign array containing its ID and campaign name , if required

```
<input type="submit" value="Generate" name="Generate" id="Generate"/>
        </br>
        <select name="Campaign" id="Campaign">
<?php foreach ( $campaign as $campaignID => $value ) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $campaignID;?>"><?php echo $value;?></option>    
<?php } ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: Must i use get or post method for retrieving info via API?

<form method="get" action="">
<h1 style="color:#0CF; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">Enter your API:</h1>
<input type="text" value="" name ="aid" id="aid" />
</br>
<select name="Campaign" id="Campaign">
<?php foreach ( $campaign as $campaignID => $value ) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $campaignID;?>"><?php echo $value;?></option>    
<?php } ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Generate" name="Generate" id="Generate"/>
</form>

Comment: yeah, want me to seperate it and use action as something.php?

Comment: Use it as POST and leave action blank as u have kept

Comment: Improve your question by giving details of result you getting for var_dump()

Comment: I'm not getting any output at the dropdown that's my problem i'm facing it >< not sure either has to be the dropdown in HTML issues.

Comment: I think server is down because;

API call failed. Server returned status code 522 on server 
on line 555

in line 555 it shows this :
if(!(($httpCode == '200') || ($httpCode == '204'))) trigger_error('API call failed. Server returned status code '.$httpCode, E_USER_ERROR);

Is it down?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ( $campaign as $campaignID => $value ) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $campaignID;?>"><?php echo $value;?></option>
```